# Carregar dependências sob demanda

Tags: javascript, ajax, requirejs

Entendo por dependência, a necessidade que seu script precise ou está acessando de alguma forma algum método/propriedade ou propriamente um objeto encapsulado em outro arquivo javascript, seja um framework ou não! Certo?

Partindo desse princípio, vi no Angular inicialmente a ideia de carregar os arquivos sob demanda, o que na minha visão melhora muito a perfomance no que refere a requisição. Porém estou no baby step do Angular. Então fiz o seguinte, dividi meu script por funcionalidade e responsabilidade sendo que ele já não era muito grande, mas não preciso carregar tudo de uma vez! (tipo componentes).

O que pega é o seguinte tenho .index com loader mais frufru com animações encadeadas em css e não apenas um gif fake, dai fiz um ajax para que carregasse meu core (conteúdo) do site para que o html não ficasse pesado pois tenho elementos (video/img/svg...). Sendo assim não quero carregar isso tudo em uma pancada só. Legal! usei o Require.js funfo!

Pergunta: Quero jogar o `require['file.js']` dentro da função que trato a requisição Ajax,para carregar apenas quando eu tiver o retorno? É possivel? Não quero carregar arquivos logo que carregar outros módulos!

```
(function(){

 require([ 'events' ], function() {
    console.log("Ok Carregou arquivo eventos")
  });

})()

var wp = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
function Ajax (mtd, file){
obj = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
obj.open(mtd, file, true);
obj.send(null);
obj.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(obj.readyState == 4 && obj.status == 200){
    wp.innerHTML=obj.responseText;
    ...}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, mas não está assim no exemplo que você deu.

No seu exemplo, você cria uma função e logo chama o método `require` de cara, fora do ajax.

Você vai ter que mover a chamada do `require` para dentro da função que trata a resposta da chamada ajax: o seu `onreadystatechange`.

E ai, tudo que depender do module `events` você joga para dentro do callback passado pro `require`... provavelmente esse callback deverá receber um argumento para você ter acesso ao módulo em si.